# Does a WebAPI2 method receiving a class as param needs FromBody

Tags: asp.net-web-api

My normal Post params looks like this:

```
public Product Foo([FromBody] Product item)
{
    // ...do something
    return item;
}
```

But I keep seeing many samples on the net where the Post method does not have the [FromBody]:

```
public Product Foo(Product item)
{
    // ...do something
    return item;
}
```

Is there a difference between these two methods?
Can they be called the same way from the client?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You only need [FromBody] when you post a simple type, like an int. The model binder automatically looks for complex types in the request body.

In your example you don't need [FromBody], as Product is a complex type.